# Do browsers lazy load hover images by default

Tags: javascript, html, css

It seems that Chrome lazy loads hover images only when they are needed. For example, an image for `:hover` is loaded only when a mouse is hovered over an element. Is this an expected behavior? Does it encompass all images or only those defined for pseudo classes? How do I force it to load all images once the page is loaded?

Comment: yes..is a expect behavior...You need to preload images to achieve what you want.  check this out -https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

Comment: I see, thanks, I'll check the link. Do all browsers lazy load images?

Comment: It depends on the size of the image, if the image is small, it is immediately...but if you have large images...it can be lazy. Another option to speed the images is using cache.

Comment: in my case in Chrome even very small images are lazy loaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome do not "preload" images which aren't actally shown and, being this a desiderable effect, all modern browser shouldnt't.

To "force" browser in having all image ready in the cache when needed you may follow different approuches:

1) Preload required images with Javascript, you can use something like this:

```
var prld = ["one.gif", "two.gif", "three.jpg", "..."];
var img = [];
for (i = 0; i < prld.length; i++) {
    img[i] = new Image();
    img[i].src = prld[i];
}
```

but you might written in different ways, of course, that's just a suggestion.

2) The second method has a different approach, it is based on the idea that with a classic Javascript preload you have anyway to make as many "calls" as the images actually are. So 10 images with preload produces 20 calls to the server... not really a desiderable thing cause the "delay" of the calls will slowup all the page load...
So we put more than one image into a single files (like a "puzzle") than we put images as a background (of an empty DIV for instance) passing a different positioning of the background trought CSS.
No need to build a unique file for ALL the images, for instance you would decide for building several mosaics of two images just for the preloading purpose; so the :hover will "replace" the background rather than make a substitution.
The technique is described here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Each of those metods has its downside, it depends on situation.

All in all, as a general consideretion, i'd avoid "hovering" at all, taking in account that, on mobile experience, is, basically, without meaning... and it would lead to additional efforts to avoid mobile "extraload" useless contens...

Comment: thanks, do you have any link to a resource describing lazy load behavior? And I assume that other browsers don't yet follow this practice?

Comment: Difficoult to describe how each single browser behaves for each single version / platform; as far as i know (but might be wrong) it doen't exist an extensive documentation about that. It's been to take in account that a page is shaped by several other elements, whose priority relatively to all the others is difficoult to describe sintetically for each browser. That's said, it might be usefull for you to use a service like this: http://www.webpagetest.org/ it shows all the loading process, usefull to understand what's acually loaded, and at which point was fetch.

Comment: Update June 2018: This is wrong, for now. All browser preload all images at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to **force** preloading for all `img`

```
var prld = document.querySelectorAll('img');
var img = [];
for (i = 0; i < prld.length; i++) {
    img[i] = new Image();
    img[i].src = prld[i].src;
}
```

This does *NOT* include images which are set in a `div` as background for example.